# How to Calculate Rest API Payload Size?

Tags: php, rest, payload

I am implementing a REST Web service API in my PHP coding, the web service have the payload size limitation of 200kb.  How can i able to calculate post json data size or payload of json data size.
So, i exactly need to calculate the payload size, i am using json data for post type.

example coding:  @curl_setopt($chaccess, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 @curl_setopt($chaccess, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_json);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the POST data size from the server end

```
(int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
```

To get the value of the post data which is sent to the client:

```
$size = strlen($post_data);
$size = $size * 8 / 1000);
if($size >= 200){
    // change the payload to 200 kb size
}else{
    // Proceed
}
```

Comment: Hi Faraj, i am using curl @curl_setopt($chaccess, CURLOPT_POST, true); @curl_setopt($chaccess, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_json);

Comment: Do you want to fetch the Maximum payload size accepted by your PHP server from CURL client? or Do you want to get the size of the payload in PHP which is send by the curl ?

Comment: No, the maximum payload size accepted for the rest api is 200kb..now, i need to send json payload within 200kb size.  Now, how can i able to calculate payload size of json data

Comment: Okey now I get your point. You have to get the length of the data in the variable $post_json isnt it? `strlen($post_json) * 8 /1000` will give the value in KB

Comment: I think, its okay.  but, i didn't get why to calculate strlen